# compiling a makefile that has an extenstion .x86

Tags: linux, makefile, terminal, x86

I have some code to compile for a library, but the author has provided different makefiles for different architectures. And each makefile has an extension e.g

- Makefile.x86
- Makefile.arm
- Makefile.aarch64

How can I make the makefile for my architecture suppose I want to use the x86

Comment: Maybe `make -f Makefile.x86` ?

Comment: Sometimes, there big 'Makefile' will detect the current system, and will automatically use the correct Makefile